# discrete math arrays and binary relations

Tags: arrays, math

Given are two arrays a and b both of length M . Given also is a binary relation R.
Specify formally a program to determine whether corresponding elements of a and b are all related by relation R.

Comment: Is this homework?  And did you have a specific language in mind?

Comment: it's homework, no specific language. But it should be shown a formal program, with the appropriate discrete math logic. I am guessing it should have a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are testing whether `a[i] R b[i]`:

```
for i=1..M:
  if not (a[i] R b[i]):
    return false
return true
```